# Open a blank window, write to it, and select the written text

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to open a blank window with Javascript, write text to it, and then select the text that I wrote, all automatically.

I have:

```
var myWindow=window.open('');
myWindow.document.write("hey");
myWindow.select();
```

which opens the window and writes the text, but does not select it.

Comment: Did you bother researching this subject at all? Where did you find the `.select` method?

Comment: Ditto, I get `undefined` for `myWindow.select` (or even `window.select`)

Answer (score 10):

This should do it:

```
var myWindow=window.open('');
myWindow.document.write("<div id='hello'>hey<div>");
var range = myWindow.document.createRange();
range.selectNode(myWindow.document.getElementById('hello'));
myWindow.getSelection().addRange(range);
myWindow.select();
```

Comment: i dont know why it has to be so complicated, but this works a dream - thanks so much!

Comment: It wont work if the popup is blocked. When I allow popup for the localhost, it started working

Answer (score 0):

```
  var popup = window.open('message.html',"'" + name + "'",'height=300,width=300,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');       
  var element = document.createElement('div');
  element.setAttribute('id', 'mydiv');
  element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('blah blah'));

  popup.window.onload = function() {

      var win = popup.document.body;
      win.appendChild(element);
      var el = popup.window.document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML;
      alert(el); //tested - ouputs 'blah blah'


 };
```