# How would I open about:blank with html code already inside of the page

Tags: javascript, html

I was using [RammerHead Browser (Proxy)](https://rammerhead.org/) and when I type in the [target URL and click "Open AB Cloaked",](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXKPL.png) (Open about:blank cloaked) it will open `about:blank` with html code visible in the Elements tab of Inspect [(Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtYbV.png). I was wondering how could I create a HTML website that can replicate this action with HTML and JavaScript.

I tried searching on Google for half an hour and found absolutely nothing, I tried different tags to help but nothing I tried worked, I want to make the redirect just have an iFrame on the `about:blank`, the size of the entire page, that's all. I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72591014/how-do-i-open-a-link-in-js-with-html-code), but they want it to open a new tab which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: The about:blank page is created by the browser not a website.

Comment: [ThiS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13202659/4935162)

Comment: What's With The Capitalized Words? It's A Little Distracting And Hard To Read.

Comment: stop using capital letter in every word !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `window.open()` with no arguments, it automatically opens `about:blank` on your webpage browser. The value returned can access that opened window, so you can do something like this:

```js
const w = window.open() // access the "about:blank" window you've opened
w.document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>You can add HTML something like this</h1>"
// or access other parts to add more JS or CSS
const style = w.document.createElement("link")
link.href = "/path/to.css"
link.rel = "stylesheet"
w.document.head.appendChild(style)
```

Note though, that the page you are referencing was automatically created by the browser, but this *can* be replicated with normal JS.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code sample for your reference

```
<a href="github.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools!</a>
```

Mentioning target as  `_blank`, it opens page in new window.

Comment: <a href="https://github.com" target="_self">Visit W3Schools!</a>

Comment: you need to format links using mini-markdown in comments. That being said, I have no idea why you're linking W3Schools and why it actually links to github.